# Declaring a list/vector/array of numpy arrays in Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Say I have several arrays, potentially of different sizes:

```
A0 = rand(3,3)
A1 = rand(4,4)
```

In Cython, I can declare their types to get fast item access:

```
cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] A0
cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] A1
```

However, say I want to access them by index:

```
A = (A0,A1)
A[0][2,1] += A[1][1,0]
```

However, now Cython doesn't know the type of `A[0]` and `A[1]`, which makes access slow. I don't think Cython has the concept of a "typed tuple". So how can I declare `A` (or a similar object) so that I still get fast item access in the above expression?

Comment: I suspect the best way is to concatenate them into a 3D array and zero (or nan) pad the places where the sizes don't match. I can't think of an obvious better way (but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist!)

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is valid `cython` is speculative, but inspired by the `cython` example at the end of:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#putting-the-inner-loop-in-cython

I'd suggest:

```
cdef foo(aTuple):
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] A0
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] A1
    A0, A1 = aTuple    # use unpacking
    A0[2,1] += A1[1,0]
```

https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/tests/run/unpack.pyx - is the unpack test `pyx`.

Or maybe use `A0 = aTuple[0]` and `A1 = aTuple[1]`; The idea is to use the array typing where it matters, for its own indexing.  The tuple just holds pointers, so the typing doesn't matter.

Another useful page when working with arrays in `cython` is http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Comment: I don't think this helps if I want to have something like `A[k]` with, say, a loop over `k`?

Comment: Not even with `for A0 in aTuple:` or `A0 = aTuple[k]`?

Comment: That misses the point; it means that I have to pay the unboxing cost from a generic Python object to an `ndarray` every time I want to access it, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I don't know if that 'unboxing' cost is significant.  Every tuple contains pointers to Python  objects, whether they are arrays, numbers or strings.  The purpose of my suggestion is to let Cython optimize the translation of the array operations.  We'd have to do some coding and timings to see whether that matters.